# Pydev can't find matplotlib modules

Tags: python, eclipse, matplotlib, pydev, importerror

I just installed matplotlib on my *windows 7 Python 2.6.5 machine* with the win32 installer . I've tried some examples from the matplotlib site to test the installation,
 under Idle everthing works fine but  *Pydev 1.9 (Eclipse 3.6)* cant find any of the sub modules.

e.g `import matplotlib` doesn't cause any errors

but `from matplotlib.path import Path` throws

```
ImportError: No module named path
```

Ive added the matplotlib path to the *system PYTHONPATH* in eclipse, is there anything else I need to do?

```
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

rect = Rectangle((-1, -1), 2, 2, facecolor="#aaaaaa")
gca().add_patch(rect)
bbox = Bbox.from_bounds(-1, -1, 2, 2)

for i in range(12):
    vertices = (np.random.random((4, 2)) - 0.5) * 6.0
    vertices = np.ma.masked_array(vertices, [[False, False], [True, True], [False, False], [False, False]])
    path = Path(vertices)
    if path.intersects_bbox(bbox):
        color = 'r'
    else:
        color = 'b'
    plot(vertices[:,0], vertices[:,1], color=color)

show()
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:\My Documents\Programming\Python\Eclipse Projects\test\src\matplotlib.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pylab import *
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "I:\My Documents\Programming\Python\Eclipse Projects\test\src\matplotlib.py", line 3, in <module>
    from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox
ImportError: No module named transforms
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that your file is called `matplotlib.py`. Then it's clear why this doesn't work: The current directory is always prepended to the system path, and your file will be found first. Since it doesn't contain a `transforms` submodule, the import will fail. `import matplotlib` itself works because there is a module called `matplotlib`—your file called `matplotlib.py`. Simply rename the file.

Comment: OMG how stupid... I ment to call it matplotlib_test.py Thanks!